# Add value to different integers in same cell in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a typical book index in a spreadsheet that goes like this:

[image]

I need Excel to recognize the different integers in the same cell and add a constant each one of them.

Let's say the constant is 5

The result should be like this:

[image]

I couldn't get excel to recognize the different values in a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents, assuming Excel ms365:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=BYROW(A1:A3,LAMBDA(a,LET(X,TEXTSPLIT(a,", "),TEXTJOIN(", ",,IFERROR(X+C1,X)))))
```

Or, if no access to `TEXTSPLIT()`, then use:

```
=BYROW(A1:A3,LAMBDA(a,LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(a,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),TEXTJOIN(", ",,IFERROR(X+C1,X)))))
```

Or, if no access to `BYROW()`, you'd have to drag the following:

```
=LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),TEXTJOIN(", ",,IFERROR(X+C$1,X)))
```

Comment: Great, thanks! But there are some values in my index like "55-60, 125-140" indicating a page range. Your formula works well but left these values untouched. Is it possible to modify the formula regarding this?

Comment: @cilginorlando which formula worked for you? Also, that's no suprise since you didn't include those type of data in your sample.

Comment: Yes, my bad, and the last one worked out well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this could be done smoothly and without using long and complex formulas.

Why don't you try to split the cell into multiple columns (`Data > Data Tools > Text To Columns > Delimited` and select `Comma` as delimiter). Once you have all different values is separate columns, it would be easy to apply formulas and add the constant.
After that, you could use `CONCATENATE` formula to merge texts and numbers back to single value in a single column.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the text and each value into separate cells, then use & to combine into the format you want, something like so:

```
=A1&", "&B1+G1&", "&C1+G1&", "&D1+G1
```

where A1 contains "Trauma" and B1 contains 15, C1 contains 17 and D1 contains 25. G1 holds the constant 5.

See
[image]

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya That is what "I would separate the text and each value into separate cells" means... As there are several ways of doing that I left that to the OP to sort. Use of left(), mid() and right(0 is possible as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have ***tried***,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Formula Applicable To Only **O365 Beta Channel (Insiders)**.

• Formula used in cell **B1**

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,TEXTBEFORE(A1,", ",1),TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(A1,", ",1),", ")+5)
```

Or, if you are not using the above Excel Version, but using either **Excel 2019, 2021 or Regular O365**, then,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **B1**

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1),IFERROR(
FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")+5,""))
```

**Edit**

One improvised approach:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,TEXTBEFORE(A1,", ",1),IFERROR(TEXTSPLIT(A1,", ")+5,""))
```

You can also accomplish this task quite easily with **Power Query**.